# Overloading operator[] for a container class with template objects

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

First of all, I have a template class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Configurable
{
    public:
    //protected:
        T var_value;
        std::string var_name;
        std::string var_type;

        Configurable()
        : var_value(0), var_name("unnamed"), var_type("undefined")
        {}
        Configurable( T v_value, std::string v_name, std::string v_type )
        : var_value(v_value), var_name(v_name), var_type(v_type)
        {}

        std::string get_name() {return var_name;}
};
```

I also have a container class named Config which has a couple of different Configurable lists for storage of Configurable ints, bools and floats. I want to overload the [] operator of Config so that it returns a Configurable with the given name (regardless of the type) from one of the lists, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
template <typename T>
Configurable<T>& operator[] ( const std::string v_name_arg );
```

The compiler returns an error of 'no match for operator[]'. So my question is - how can I make this work? Is it even possible to do it using templates or should I find a different approach with inheritance?

EDIT: Sorry for all the confusion. Here's the container class I'm talking about:

```
class Config
{
    public:
    //private:
    std::list < Configurable<int>    > list_int;
    std::list < Configurable<float>  > list_float;
    std::list < Configurable<double> > list_double;
    std::list < Configurable<bool>   > list_bool;

    //public:
    Config(){}

    template <typename T>
    Configurable<T>& operator[] ( const std::string &v_name_arg );
};
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example showing the problem. In particular, show where you declared the `operator[]`, and where you try to use it. On the other hand, most details of your class `Configurable` are probably unimportant for your problem (you'll find out when you produce the MWE).

Comment: A function template where (at least) one template parameter is not deduced must be called by explicitly providing the non-deduced template parameter. Since operator overloading tries to simplify (or harmonize) syntax, this doesn't work well for operator function templates. You had to call them like `obj.operator[] <int> (arg)`, there's no variant like `obj[arg]<int>`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fd06677eb9409c8)

Comment: Your class has no `operator[]` but an `operator[]` template. Since its template parameters cannot be deduced from the arguments, you need to provide them explicitly, e.g. `config.operator[]<int>("foo")`. Which of course makes the `operator[]` syntax rather useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with declaring the templated `operator[]` without any argument that depends on the template parameter is that the compiler cannot determine the type `T` from a call in the form `config["name"]`.
One solution, considering code readability, would be changing the `operator[]` to a method such as:

```
template <typename T>
Configurable<T>& get ( const std::string v_name_arg );
```

Then, the call should be written like:

```
config.get<int>("name")
```

Also, consider passing the string by reference (`const std::string&`) to avoid unnecessary copies of a `std::string` passed to the method/operator.

Answer (score 0):

As described above, it's a syntax error.

WHen you write:

```
template <typename T>
Configurable<T>& operator[] ( const std::string v_name_arg );
```

You try to define a free standing operator[] as if it would be a free standing function.
But according to your explanations, operator[] should be a member of your container Config.

So the its definition should look somewhat like:

```
template <typename T>
class Config {
    //...
public:
    Configurable<T>& operator[] (const std::string v_name_arg) { /* return a ref to a Configurable */ };
};
```

With such a definition, the stuff compiles, and you can use it for example with :

```
int main()
{
    Configurable<int> c; 
    Config<int> cfg; 

    auto a = cfg["test"]; 
}
```

Comment: Actually the operator overload was inside the Config class, I should have specified that. Also, the Config class has multiple containers of different Configurable types, not just one, so unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok ! Is your `Container` a template class ?  Or do you only use instantated templates therin (i.e. Configurable<int>, Configurable<bool>, etc...> ?  Could you possibly show us what this class looks like (expecially the definition of the containers accross which you whant to index) ?

Comment: *"You try to define a free standing operator[] as if it would be a free standing function."* A free `operator[]` would have *2* parameters. This is not a (syntax) error, it is just not very useful.

Comment: @dyp I was troubled as this operator was apparently declared outside a class, whereas standard says in *13.5.5 Subscripting* : *operator[] shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter.*

Comment: Oh, right. I can never remember which ones are allowed as non-members. It is a valid member function template, though.

Comment: @dyp of course, as a member it's valid. And your living example above very interesting. For me it's now not 100% clear how Chudej designed his Container if it's not a template of T.